# Azure b2c Forgot password link not woking

Tags: azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

I'm doing xamarin-forms application with azure mobile and azure ad b2c. Everything else is working great except "Forgot your password" link.

[image: Azure AD b2c login]

[image]

Screenshots are from UWP client. Android client and Azure portal profile tests dont work either but give different error "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Is there something wrong with my sign-in/sign-up b2c policy settings or is this supposed work yet at all? All help appreciated

Comment: Practically guaranteed it is something with your AAD B2C policy.  If you are getting the login screen and are able to log in normally, then the azure mobile apps bit is not the problem.

Comment: Actually, there's a problem with this.  A sign-in policy works fine as the user gets a prompt `Can't access your account?`. That is handled by B2C and not returned to the client.  The sign-up/sign-in policy shows a `Forgot password?` prompt.  They do two different things and the latter just returns `Unauthorized` to the app.  Since it doesn't catch it, using a server oriented approach with a webview on a device doesn't work.  it will always show `Not authorized` on the screen.  At least it has for me.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the forgot password link on this page, B2C will redirect back to your application with an error message.  The expected behavior is that the MSAL library will capture the redirect, throw an exception, which you can capture and then use to redirect to a password reset policy.

It looks like MSAL is failing to capture that redirect for some reason.  Then I'd recommend opening an issue on the code sample or library you're using.  But before doing so, I would double check that you're using the right `redirect_uri`, and capture a network trace if possible.  It would be necessary to know the exact web requests that occurred during this flow, and which URL is resulting in the error message above.